# Python 3 Requests - How to make a post request, fill in forms and submit

Tags: python, forms, python-3.x, python-requests

In a website with this code from flask:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/upload', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def upload():
    return """
        <html>
          <body>
            <h1>Guess what! I am a title!</h1>
              <form action="/run" method="POST" name="upload">
                <input type="password" name="password">
                <input type="file" name="file" />
              </form>
          </body>
        </html>"""


@app.route('/run', methods=["POST"])
def download_file():
    if request.form['password'] == 'hey':
        request.files['file'].save('/home/james/site.txt')
        return "File uploaded successfully!"
    else:
        return "Wrong password"
```

How can I run a proper post request and get the output of `/run`?
So far I've tried:

```
upload = {'password': 'whatever',
          'file': open(my_files_location, 'rb')}
r = requests.post('http://jamesk.pythonanywhere.com/upload', data=upload)
```

But the website neither has run the form nor did it return what I wanted. This is what I get when I run `r.content`:

```
b'\n        <html>\n          <body>\n            <h1>Guess what! I am a title!</h1>\n              <form action="/run" method="POST" name="upload">\n                <input type="password" name="password">\n                <input type="file" name="file" />\n              </form>\n          </body>\n        </html>'
```

When I expected `b'Wrong password'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting to the form path, not the form *handler* path. Your browser reads the `action="/run"` attribute on the form and uses that as the target to post to. You need to do the same:

```
url = 'http://jamesk.pythonanywhere.com/run'
```

Note that the URL ends in `/run`, **not** `/upload`.

Next, you need to fix your form handling; you need to configure the form to use the [right mimetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) and use the [`files` option to upload files](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) in `requests`:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def upload():
    return """
        <html>
          <body>
            <h1>Guess what! I am a title!</h1>
              <form action="/run" method="POST" name="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="password" name="password">
                <input type="file" name="file" />
              </form>
          </body>
        </html>"""
```

and

```
r = requests.post(url, 
    data={'password': 'hey'}, 
    files={'file': open(my_files_location, 'rb')})
```

Comment: With the code in my question this is the content I get when I insert the correct password(`hey`) `b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>\n'`. Sorry for not putting this in the main question.

Comment: @jameskaly: don't put this into the question, that is now solved. You have a new issue. That's an error message returned by Flask, look at the logs that Flask produces to learn more as to why it is going wrong.

Comment: @jameskaly: if you can't solve it from that information, you should post a *new* question. Do include the error messages you found in the logs too.

Comment: @jameskaly: answer updated, you missed some details in the [Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file).